# cq5 orderby clause for whole result set

Tags: sorting, pagination, aem

I am trying order the results of the query, it is doing the sorts on each page. If I set 10 result per page it is sorting only on this page. Instead, I want all the resultset to be sorted 
Here is my predicate query
      map.put("1_orderby", "@jcr:content/pageTitle");
      map.put("1_orderby.sort", "asc");
      map.put("1_orderby.index", "true");
      map.put("2_orderby", "@jcr:content/jcr:description");
      map.put("2_orderby.sort", "asc");
      map.put("2_orderby.index", "true");

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "sorts on each page". As far as i know it sorts the entire result set, but displays only the first "x" results, where x is the number of results configured per page (by default it is 10).

Comment: Each page has a sorting from A to z, Lets say if I get 30 results wiht 10 results per page, on first page I have sorting from A to z, on the second page it starts again from a to z and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The order by sorts the entire result set and not just the result on a single page.
But the reason why you are not able to get the desired result is, it does a case-sensitive comparison for sorting the result set, due to which all the results with **A to Z** appear first followed by **a to z**. i.e., *Bat* comes before *apple* and *Zebra* before *cat*.

In case you want to perform a case-insensitive ordering, then you might need to implement a Custom Predicate Evaluator and provide a Customr Comparator to sort the result set(which might be expensive).